# Callback is returning 'Request GET' instead of an item

Tags: python, scrapy

I created web crawler using Scrapy in Python. But it seems doesn't work as I would like to. I would be grateful for any help with that.

Spider is scraping a site with cars (`http://allegro.pl/osobowe-volkswagen-4055?buyUsed=1`). I have problems with recursive crawling (following links). I want my spider follows the subcategories until it reach category where there is no other subcategory. So:`Volkswagen-> Golf ->I (1974-1983)`.

For each nod I want to have name, number of cars, if there are subnode then a link to it, and as a 'subcategory' an object with the same complete of information for a subnode.

items.py:
import scrapy

```
class Allegro3Item(scrapy.Item):
    name=scrapy.Field()
    count=scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    subcategory= scrapy.Field()
```

Spider code:

```
import scrapy

from allegro3.items import Allegro3Item

linki=[]

class AlegroSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "AlegroSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["allegro.pl"]
    #start_urls = ["http://allegro.pl/samochody-osobowe-4029?buyUsed=1"]
    #start_urls=["http://allegro.pl/osobowe-buick-18092?buyUsed=1"]
    #start_urls=["http://allegro.pl/osobowe-alfa-romeo-4030?buyUsed=1"]
    start_urls=['http://allegro.pl/osobowe-volkswagen-4055?buyUsed=1']

    def parse(self, response):

        global linki

        if response.url not in linki:

            #add links to the list
            linki.append(response.url)

            # if it is not dead end
            if len(response.xpath('//*[@id="sidebar-categories"]/div/nav/ul/li').extract()) == \
                len(response.xpath('//*[@id="sidebar-categories"]/div/nav/ul/li/a').extract()):
                for de in response.xpath('//*[@id="sidebar-categories"]/div/nav/ul/li'):

                    #create iteam
                    la = Allegro3Item()
                    link = de.xpath('a/@href').extract()

                    # populate iteam
                    la['name'] = de.xpath('a/span/span/text()').extract()[0].encode('utf-8')
                    la['count'] = de.xpath('span/text()').extract()[0].encode('utf-8')
                    la['url'] = response.urljoin(link[0]).encode('utf-8')
                    la['subcategory']=[]

                    #Go to subnodes
                    if la['url'] is not None:
                        if la['url'] not in linki:
                            linki.append(la['url'])

                            #setting request
                            request = scrapy.Request(la['url'],callback=self.SearchFurther) 
                            request.meta['la'] = la

                    yield request

    def SearchFurther(self,response):
        global linki

        # get metadata from request
        la = response.meta['la']

        #check if this is not deadend: lower number of category than number of links
        if len(response.xpath('//*[@id="sidebar-categories"]/div/nav/ul/li').extract()) == \
                len(response.xpath('//*[@id="sidebar-categories"]/div/nav/ul/li/a').extract()):

            #go further
            for de in response.xpath('//*[@id="sidebar-categories"]/div/nav/ul/li'):

                #populate subnode
                la2 = Allegro3Item()
                la2['name'] = de.xpath('a/span/span/text()').extract()[0].encode('utf-8')
                la2['count'] = de.xpath('span/text()').extract()[0].encode('utf-8')
                link = de.xpath('a/@href').extract()
                la2['url'] = response.urljoin(link[0]).encode('utf-8')
                la2['subcategory']=[]

                # if there is subnode, looping
                if la2['url'] is not None:
                    if la2['url'] not in linki:
                        linki.append(la2['url'])

                        #make recursive request to get sub/sub nodes
                        request = scrapy.Request(la2['url'],callback=self.SearchFurther)
                        request.meta['la']=la2

                        #attach response as subcategory
                        la2['subcategory'].append(request)

                la['subcategory'].append(la2)
        else:
            la['subcategory']=[]                


        yield la
```

Example output:

```
{"count": 509, "url": "http://allegro.pl/volkswagen-transporter-83759?buyUsed=1", "name": "Transporter",
 "subcategory":

    [{"count": "(6)", "url": "http://allegro.pl/transporter-t2-83761?buyUsed=1", "name": " T2 "
    , "subcategory": ["<Request GET http://allegro.pl/transporter-t2-83761?buyUsed=1>"]}

    , {"count": "(14)", "url": "http://allegro.pl/transporter-t3-83762?buyUsed=1", "name": " T3 "
    , "subcategory": ["<Request GET http://allegro.pl/transporter-t3-83762?buyUsed=1>"]}

    , {"count": "(231)", "url": "http://allegro.pl/transporter-t4-83763?buyUsed=1", "name": " T4 "
    , "subcategory": ["<Request GET http://allegro.pl/transporter-t4-83763?buyUsed=1>"]}

    , {"count": "(256)", "url": "http://allegro.pl/transporter-t5-83764?buyUsed=1", "name": " T5 "
    , "subcategory": ["<Request GET http://allegro.pl/transporter-t5-83764?buyUsed=1>"]}]},
```

So I understand that everything is going good until moment of recursive request (line 79, when I'm using SearchFurther callback and want to use it one more time to scrap subcategory),because I'm getting
`"subcategory": ["<Request GET http://allegro.pl/transporter-t2-83761?buyUsed=1>"]}` 
insted of an item:`line 90: yield la`

If you suspect what I'm doing wrong I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: `SearchFurther` yields an `Allegro3Item` instance, with one of the keys, `"subcategory"`, containing a `Request` object. For Scrapy, this is still an `Item`, it will not check what's inside and enqueue those `Request`s. You could yield the Request objects after `yield la`, for example `for r in la['subcategory']: yield r`, and even not use the item as a container for those subsequent requests

Comment: @paul, thank you for the answer. I'm struggling with your answer since 2 days and I don't know how to implement it. I think that I understand theory but i don't know how to implement it in practice. If I try to loop request I'm getting error: request is not iterable. If I do it after [yield la], it is working but I'm getting results not as a 'subcategory' of la item/object but as an another la item/object. If there is a way to yield request and attach it to ['subcategory field']?